# Exit button in Air Android flash professional CS6 based application

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-button

How can i create an exit button from my application using Air for Android Flash Professional CS6. do I need to create a button? and what is the code for that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here you have AIR solution, this should work.

1) Create a button

2) Add Event listener to the button

```
 button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitHandler );
```

3) copy and paste this code to your project

```
     import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

     //Then you can use the following function for the button click handler: 

   function exitHandler (event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
      NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(); 
    }
```

merry christmas =)

**EDIT**

Hi. I just now saw your comment.
And to test, I created a new project of type AIR for Android. First I added a button to stage, and gave it a name of "btn_exit". And the only AS3 I have is this:

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

stop();

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

btn_exit.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, exitApp);

function exitApp(event:TouchEvent):void {

     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();    
}
```

This should work for you. xD

Comment: Scene 22, Layer 'Actions', Frame 82, Line 19 1120: Access of undefined property NativeApplication.
 i got this

Comment: Hey, I added an NEW example to my answer. (look up).
Should help. xD

Comment: do I need to export the file into Android platform to make the exit button functioning ?

Comment: No. You can simulate the android device in Flash, and with that you can test your button.
Make sure you have the project type AIR for Android 3.X, then go to:

**Control->Test Movie->in AIR Debug Luncher (Mobile)**.
On the screen will pop up your movie and at the side pops up a **Simulator** window, in that window select **Touch and Gesture** tab, and in there choose **Touch Layer** to simulate a touch screen. And finally try you button.
**To fully understand click on the link and watch it:**
[link](http://www.youtube.com/v/FNk1fTw5zQE&start=57&end=217&version=3)

Comment: I tried to do, there are No errors  but the button still not working . anyway, many thanks